# removeChild work only every other time

Tags: javascript

I try put one element next second, and delete second element, but it does not work.
Look at example: http://jsfiddle.net/CZCGG/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of `getElementsByTagName` is a live node list.  As you manipulate the elements the pseudo-array you have will get updated in real-time.

Specifically each time around the loop your `i` value is jumping too far ahead, because the element *after* the one you just removed now has that original element's index.

To resolve that you should work from the end of the array backwards.  This ensures that each element retains its original index as the loop progresses.

You should also use `Node.replaceChild` instead of an `insertBefore`, `removeChild` sequence

see http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/pfnGX/

```
var  span = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

for (var i = span.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = "http://jsfiddle.net/";
    a.innerHTML = "http://jsfiddle.net/ " + i; 

    var s = span[i];
    s.parentNode.replaceChild(a, s);
}​
```

Answer (score 2):

You are operating on a node list. Each time you remove an item, the list gets shorter and everything shuffles down … but you are still incrementing the index.

Comment: This got me the first time I was editing a dynamic list too :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
http://jsfiddle.net/gYwSq/1/

```
    var  span = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    for(i=0; span.length!=0; i++){
       var a = document.createElement("a");
       a.href = "http://jsfiddle.net/";
       a.innerHTML = "http://jsfiddle.net/ " + i; 
       span[0].parentNode.insertBefore(a, span[0]);
       span[0].parentNode.removeChild(span[0]);
    }​
```